# I have an array and i want to get the equivalent index of specific item(selected from autocomplettextview)

Tags: android, arraylist, autocompletetextview

this is my mainactivity

```
    TestAdapter mdh = new TestAdapter(this); 
    mdh.open(); 
    ArrayList<String> songs = mdh.getAllSongs();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, songs);


    AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
            findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_songs);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
    textView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

As you can see.. adapter has all the songs and pass down to the autocompletetextview
what i want is when i click an item on the autocompletetextview..i will get its index number and store it on an integer..i want its index from the arraylist and not its index from the dropdown..please help me...

Comment: use `arg2` in `onItemClick`

Comment: ive done that but i need the index of the item from the array list and not on the dropdownlist

Comment: `arg2` will give you the index of the item clicked. Also does the number of items in drop list match the one in the arraylist?

Comment: or better how do i get its string value?

Comment: no..its does not match it..i want the static index from the arraylist..

Comment: adapter has all songs. so your drop down has all songs . so why would this not work  `String str = songs.get(pos)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 TestAdapter mdh = new TestAdapter(this); 
mdh.open(); 
ArrayList<String> songs = mdh.getAllSongs();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, songs);


AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
        findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_songs);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);
textView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      Log.i("GiveTag", arg2); // it will give you what ever item clicked position /index 


    }
});
```

Comment: this is the same..it will also return the index on the dropdown and not on the real arraylist..tnx though..any other suggestions my friend?

Comment: try this Log.i("GiveTag", _songs.indexOf(arg2);

Comment: or better how do i get its string value?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
textView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {
                String str = songs.get(pos);
            }
        });
```

Comment: the pos will only return its current position in the Dropdown list..for example..if i have an 10 items on the array and the dropdown will only show 2..the index of the first item is 0 and the second is 1.. but on the array for example its index is 7 and 8..what i want is to retrieve 7 or 8 on OnClick.its index on the the array of songs.. please help me

Comment: or better how do i get its string value?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works

```
textView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                        long arg3) {
                    String text = textView.getText().toString();
                    int position = songs.indexOf(text);

                }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

Object data = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
int pos = java.util.Arrays.asList(songs).indexOf(data);           

}
});
```